# How to get the last message properties in Azure Service Bus Explorer

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

I'm currently facing an issue while attempting to access the `Service Bus Explorer` using a `Python` script on a remote machine. My script aims to peek at the last message and print its properties, but it seems to encounter some obstacles hindering its functionality.

`LinkDetach('ErrorCodes.NotAllowed: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver. TrackingId:c41edfdvfaf-7a70-4a88-924d-15ec4e61141d_B30, SystemTracker:G4:38014551:receiver-link-885e6d3fsdf-07c8-4b2d-9017-bfhdgdc0b31, Timestamp:2024-02-22T06:01:29 TrackingId:0d0eee73bcdva447cdfdfs59ad9671c18e_G4, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2024-02-22T06:01:29`

Below is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

def get_last_message_properties(namespace_name, topic_name, subscription_name):
try:
#Create a Service Bus client using DefaultAzureCredential
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient(
fully_qualified_namespace=namespace_name,
credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
)

    # Get a subscription client
    subscription_client = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(
        topic_name=topic_name,
        subscription_name=subscription_name
    )

    # Receive messages from the subscription
    with subscription_client:
        messages = subscription_client.receive(max_message_count=1)
        for message in messages:
            try:
                # Access message properties
                properties = message.properties
                cdId = properties.get("cdId")
                active = properties.get("active")
                alarm = properties.get("alarm")
                print(f"Last message properties: cdId={cdId}, active={active}, alarm={alarm}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
namespace = "sbdev.servicebus.windows.net"
topic = "topicsystemlog_main"
subscription = "SubCardDBUpdater_20"
get_last_message_properties(namespace, topic, subscription)
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver.

Your `SubCardDBUpdater_20` subscription has sessions enabled. When you're attempting to access it, you need to create your receiver passing in the session ID (`session_id` argument for the `servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver()` call. Which makes your task more complicated as it's not just a last message but rather a last message in a specific session.